How to coverage classes from URLClassLoader in Eclipse with EclEmma?
My application use a small launcher which build then a hierarchy of a URLClassLoaders from plugins. The URLClassLoader can also point to other projects in which I develop the plugin. If I want measure the coverage with EclEmma then it coverage only the classes of the launcher self not of the linked classes.
How can I measure the coverage of classes in custom classloaders, for example URLClassLoaders? Are there any settings in Eclipse that make this possible?

Do you really export and run tests from other projects in "this" project? I rather would try to write and run those white-box-tests in their respective projects and maybe combine the results into one big coverage report (but tbh I don't know how I would do that... ;-)

Without a minimal reproducible example it is unclear about what you talking (does it matter that the launcher is small; which kind of plugins; etc.). "The URLClassLoader can also point to other projects" - can? Are the not covered classes in projects on which the project containing the launcher depends or not? If not, does adding those projects in Project > Properties: Java Build Path, tab Projects help?

@cyberbrain I does not want run unit tests. I want run the real application to find dead code which is only used from unit tests.

@howlger The classes are not in the project A of the launcher. It is also not possible to add the second project B to the Java Build path of project A because the classes would then load from the boot-classloader and not from the URLClassLoader. This a minimal description of my setup. The reality is many more complex.

The coverage configuration uses the project's Java Build Path by default, but in your coverage configuration in the Dependencies tab you can edit the classpath to be used. There is also the tab Coverage where you can choose what to coverage.

In the tab Coverage you can only select sources that are on the boot classpath. I want select coverage classes which are not on the classpath.

You need to run coverage in the context of the project containing the classes for which you want to do the coverage analysis, not in the context of the project containing the launcher. Just like you would do for an OSGi bundle or Eclipse plugin. A minimal reproduce example would have shown exactly what you did and thereby revealed earlier that you did this wrong.

With JaCoCO it is possible to measure the coverage of any class from any custom ClassLoader because there are no limits on the command line parameters. But it is not integrated in Eclipse.

This answer seems to be wrong, based on wrong assumptions.
